# Messed up function needs uncovering!

Tags: computer-puzzle, computer-science

You spent 5 hours to make a simple function that takes in a number, and it will print out a grid with the given number as each of its dimensions. Each square of the grid will have a single circle in the center.

Satisfied, you save the code in `grid.py` and go to bed.

Later, you accidentally run your scrambler program *(a program that will randomly choose one character in a file, and swap its position with another random character in that file)* on your `grid.py`... three times! Frantically, you run `grid.py` to see if any damage has been done.

You input `1`, the program returns

```
-----
| O |
-----
```

You breathe a sigh of relief, and casually run the program again.

You input `2`, the program returns

```
------
| O ||
------
------
```

You freeze. You expected to see this instead:

```
---------
| O | O |
---------
| O | O |
---------
```

Shaking, you try `3`.

The program returns

```
-------
| O |||
-------
-------
-------
```

You hoped to see this:

```
-------------
| O | O | O |
-------------
| O | O | O |
-------------
| O | O | O |
-------------
```

This was the function:

```
def grid(num):
    secret = ...
    print('\n'.join(secret))
```

For you challenge, uncover how `secret` was defined, and how it's defined after the accident.

Comment: @Bass If you say so :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

> ```
> (lambda l,O,num: [l,O]*num+[l])("----"*num+"-","| O "*num+"|",num)
> ```

Demonstration:

> ```
> secret_str = """(lambda l,O,num: [l,O]*num+[l])("----"*num+"-","| O "*num+"|",num)"""
> ```
>
> ```
> accidict = {ord("*"):"+",ord("+"):"*"}
> ```

No spoilers in code below.

```
def grid(num):
    secret = eval(secret_str)
    print('\n'.join(secret))


grid(1)
# -----
# | O |
# -----
grid(2)
# ---------
# | O | O |
# ---------
# | O | O |
# ---------
grid(3)
# -------------
# | O | O | O |
# -------------
# | O | O | O |
# -------------
# | O | O | O |
# -------------

# accident
secret_str = secret_str.translate(accidict)

grid(1)
# -----
# | O |
# -----
grid(2)
# ------
# | O ||
# ------
# ------
grid(3)
# -------
# | O |||
# -------
# -------
# -------
```

Comment: Here https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105736/773001

Comment: Thanks @riskymysteries. Good job we don't have to post any real code with that.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, can you explain?

Comment: @riskymysteries I mean it's good enough for very small snippets but a pain in the backside for anything with more than 5 lines or so.